# Unable to execute fabric script for vagrant box

Tags: python, django, postgresql, vagrant, fabric

I am trying to run a fabric script which is uploading data in a postgres database in a vagrant box. The same script was running fine a couple of months ago and nothing was changed. But this time when I execute the script from my host machine as:

```
./pipeline-import.sh
```

But then I get a strange behavior. 
First I am requested to enter a password for the vagrant user, while before I was never requested. After I put the default pass: vagrant
I get these errors:

```
Loaded environment from env/dev.yml
[localhost:2222] Executing task 'pipeline_sql_schemas'
Continue (y/n)? y
[localhost:2222] sudo: echo 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS gaul;' | PGPASSWORD='xxxx' psql -U user -d user_db
[localhost:2222] Login password for 'vagrant': 
 No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"

 Fatal error: No existing session

 Underlying exception:
   No existing session

 Aborting.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are asked `Login password for 'vagrant':`, it does not happen in your own terminal. Hence, should you type anything (even the right password), it will result in an error, like the one you experienced.

One way to overcome this is to declare your default password in the `env` variable, along with the VM's username